# Convert Markdown to HTML without allowing HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, angular, markdown, angular10

I'm trying to build a `textarea` that supports markdown. I've succeeded in converting the markdown to HTML in order to present a preview, Using the following pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as marked from 'marked';
import * as DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

@Pipe({ name: 'markdown' })
export class MarkdownPipe implements PipeTransform {

  markdownToSafeHtml(value: string): string {
    const html = marked(value);
    const safeHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(html);
    return safeHtml;
  }

  transform(str: string): string {
    if (str && str.length > 0) {
      const html = this.markdownToSafeHtml(str);
      return html.toString();
    }

    return str;
  }
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="value | markdown">
```

It's working and showing the markdown design, but the problem is that I can add any HTML tags in the markdown string, and because I'm using `innerHTML` the div will use them, for example using `<h1>hello</h1>` presents in the preview in this tag, and it should present it as a text.

1. How can I convert to markdown, without the rest of the HTML Tags?
2. I've already tried to encode the HTML letters (for example `&amp;` and so on), the problem is when using the code markdown, the conversion of this: `<div>example</div>` is `&lt;div&gt;example&lt;/div&gt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally succeeded using the pipeline below.

The solution was to create an element containing the HTML and reverse the HTML escape in the `<code>` elements using the `unescapeCodes` function.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as marked from 'marked';
import * as DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

@Pipe({ name: 'markdown' })
export class MarkdownPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() {

  }

  private escapeHTML(str: string) {
    return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
  }

  private unescapeHTML(str: string) {
    return str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
      .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
      .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
      .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
      .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
  }

  private markdownToSafeHtml(value: string): string {
    const html = marked(value);
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(html);
  }

  private unescapeCodes(value: string) {
    const el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = value;
    const codes = el.getElementsByTagName('code');
    for (let i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
      codes.item(i).innerText = this.unescapeHTML(codes.item(i).innerText);
    }

    return el.innerHTML.toString();
  }

  transform(str: string): string {
    if (!str || str.length == 0) return str;

    str = this.escapeHTML(str);
    let html = this.markdownToSafeHtml(str);
    html = this.unescapeCodes(html);
    return html;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not allow escaped html to be inserted into a code block